# Switch value in Django models.BooleanField with class base view by click on button

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Working on a ToDo list as a practice project.

[This  is my GitHub link](https://github.com/MKeSiMu/todo-list-practice/tree/develop)

This is my models.py:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Task(models.Model):
    TASK_STATUS_CHOICES = [(False, 'Not done'), (True, 'Done')]
    content = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Enter date and time in '2023-05-13 06:31' format"
    )
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        choices=TASK_STATUS_CHOICES
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="tasks")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["is_completed", "-created"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

I want to switch the True/False value of **is_completed ** field by clicking on the button.

In all examples I can find in internet, it's  done with the help of func base view, so I did it like this:

**view.py**:

```
def task_complete_or_undo(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    task.is_completed = not task.is_completed
    task.save()
    return redirect("/")
```

**urls.py**:

```
path(
        "task/<int:pk>/task-status",
        task_complete_or_undo,
        name="task-status"
    ),
```

**index.html**

```
{% if task.is_completed %}
        <span style="color: green">{{ task.get_is_completed_display }}</span>
        <a href="{% url 'todo_list_app:task-status' pk=task.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm link-to-page float-right">
          Undo
        </a>
      {% else %}
        <span style="color: red">{{ task.get_is_completed_display }}</span>
        <a href="{% url 'todo_list_app:task-status' pk=task.id %}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm link-to-page float-right">
          Complete
        </a>
      {% endif %}
```

This works for me, but my mentor asked me to rewrite it in the class base view.

His advise is create view like this:
**views.py**:

```
class TaskStatusUpdateView(View):

    @staticmethod
    def post(request, pk):
        task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
        task.is_done = not task.is_done
        task.save()
        return redirect("todo_list_app:index")
```

and I tried to do so, but when I press the button, the server get the error  **Method Not Allowed**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwTYu.png)

I searched a lot, but can't find anything that close to the answer I need.

What I only came up with is an idea to change the model view to UpdateView like this:

```
class TaskStatusUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ["is_completed"]

    @staticmethod
    def update(request, pk):
        task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
        task.is_done = not task.is_done
        task.save()
        return redirect("todo_list_app:index")
```

In this case, by clicking on the button I go to the update form, where the value of the is_completed field changed, but need to press submit button to save it. In this case, I need to figure out how to auto-submit this form and in this case, it will be a workable claas base view.

But I doubt this is the right way. So the question is still here: how to switch these values by clicking the button using the class based view?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
**views.py**:

```
class TaskStatusUpdateView(View):

    @staticmethod
    def post(request, pk):
        task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
        task.is_done = not task.is_done
        task.save()
        return redirect("todo_list_app:index")
```

to make post request in index.html need to add **form** with **csrf_token**

```
{% if task.is_completed %}
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'todo_list_app:task-status' task.id %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm link-to-page float-right" type="submit" value="Undo">
        </form>
        <span style="color: green">{{ task.get_is_completed_display }}</span>
      {% else %}
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'todo_list_app:task-status' task.id %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm link-to-page float-right" type="submit" value="Complete">
        </form>
        <span style="color: red">{{ task.get_is_completed_display }}</span>
      {% endif %}
```

And everything works, can change value of models.BooleanField to True/False.